# How to run remote script with sudo access

Tags: expect

I am trying to run a remote script which need to run as a sudo but its unable to run the script as sudo. Is my approach is correct to do sudo? Please help..Thanks in advance.

```
 spawn ssh -t {*}$ssh_opts $user@$ip bash $script {*}$argv
```

Comment: Where is the `sudo` command ? Any error messages ?

Comment: Im not getting any error messages but my script is getting failing as it should run with sudo after ssh. Can you please suggest the above command I have used is correct way to do sudo with spawn ssh?

Comment: Add `sudo` before your remote script name ?

Comment: `spawn ssh ... sudo bash $script ...`

Comment: Thanks Dinesh @glenn jackman its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn -noecho bash -c "ssh user@host \"sudo su -c 'your_command' - sudo_user\""

expect {
    -re ".*assword:"{
        send "password\r"
        exp_continue
    } eof {
        wait
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.!!!